# Ballerina Fork/Join with sql:ClientConnector behaivor

Tags: ballerina

I created a resource on a service to parallelize two DB selects using Fork/Join and receive the error at the second worker:

**exception in workerdemodb2 : error in ballerina program: 8**

If I replace one of the workers returning a hardcoded json variable instead the sql:ClientConnect.select... everything works fine.

Example of the worker:

```
            worker emp (message m) {
                string dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:49161/XE";
                string username = "vatrox";
                string password = "vatrox";
                map propertiesMap = {"jdbcUrl":dbURL, "username":username, "password":password};
                sql:ClientConnector empDBConnector = create sql:ClientConnector(propertiesMap);
                sql:Parameter[] params = [];

                try {
                    datatable dt = sql:ClientConnector.select(empDBConnector, "select empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno from emp", params);
                    json payload = datatables:toJson(dt);
                    message response = {};
                    messages:setJsonPayload(response, payload);
                    reply response;

                }
                catch (exception e) {
                    message response = {};
                    messages:setJsonPayload(response, responseException("select emp",e));
                    reply response;

                }
            }
```

Another thing... 
Can I reuse a sql:ClientConnector with different workers? Because I created a global one, but I received an error of not defined variable, so I needed to create a new one for each worker.

Thank you,

JP

Comment: It's strange. If I put the code that is inside the worker on a function, and call the function, it works. JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've improved the design of Ballerina workers. Now they can access variables from their parent scopes, which means now you can share an sql:ClientConnector across multiple workers, resources.  You can find more information of this design in this document. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ovnsu_Ifjysjg3OUH0QE3aalnV_0hMtrs38QJheyYaw/edit?ts=58e1c3e6#